# Rails 5 - in link_to, how to pass a nil (NULL) param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, routes, link-to

I have a link where I need to pass a sequence of params, where 2 params are always nill.

```
link_to go_to_action_path(id, par_01, par_02, par_03, par_04)
```

In some cases are the `par_01` and `par_02` `nil`, in other `par_03` and `par_04`.

If I have these values in the variables:

```
par_01 = nil
par_02 = nil
par_03 = 'a'
par_04 = 'b'
```

And then in the `go_to_action` action:

```
p01 = params[:par_01]
p02 = params[:par_02]
p03 = params[:par_03]
p04 = params[:par_04]
```

I get these values:

```
p01 => a
p02 => b
p03 => 
p04 =>
```

In other words, the variables `par_01` and `par_02` will be thrown away and on their places will be moved in `par_03` and `par_04`.

How can I force the `link_to` to accept a param with a `nil` value? I was thinking about placing there `0`s instead of `nil`s and then manually parse it in the controller action, but this is quite an ugly solution.

Comment: Not sure we have enough to go on. What is `go_to_action_path`? Is it a route? If so, what? If a method, we need the source.

Comment: That's an example of a path to a controller action (yes, it is a route). The above is a pseudocode. The question here is how to pass a `nil` value through a param and "receive" it on the other end in the controller action.

Comment: Nimish's answer is probably the right one, but it would really help to see that controller action.  Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Have you tried using `&` in your ERB? Simply put, it lets code work even if a param is `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `hash` as the second option with id in your route

Use

`link_to go_to_action_path(id, { par_01: par_01, par_02: par_02, par_03: par_03, par_04: par_04 })`

Instead of

`link_to go_to_action_path(id, par_01, par_02, par_03, par_04)`

Then, In Controllers, say action name is `action`

```
# here you can use your params
def action
  p01 = params[:par_01]
  p02 = params[:par_02]
  p03 = params[:par_03]
  p04 = params[:par_04]
end
```